# attribute menu not found in NavigationView

Tags: android

when i use controls com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView in my xml
file, i got the error:

> error: attribute menu (aka cn.cupde.android:menu) not found.

here is my xml file:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_home"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/top_actionbar"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fl_main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and the whole error log:

```html
Android resource linking failed
Output:  /app/src/main/res/layout/activity_home.xml:30: 
error: attribute headerLayout (aka cn.cupde.android:headerLayout) not found.
error: attribute menu (aka cn.cupde.android:menu) not found.
error: failed linking file resources
```

here is my build.gradle file:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cn.cupde.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'

}
```

what can i do? btw i use:

AndroidStudio3.2Preview

gradle-plugin-version 3.2.0-beta04

Answer (score 1):

As in build.gradle target version is 28 `com.android.support:design:26.1.0` will not work as design support version should not be below the target version .

I would like to suggest lower the SDK version to 26 and use the `com.android.support:design:26.1.0`will . and sync the gradle , it will solve attribute error.

For reference use below dependency `

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

`
and adjust compileSdkVersion.

After adding the above dependencies sync the project

Comment: thank u, i used androidstudio3.1, it's worked, but androidstudio3.2 preview not,i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your Gradle dependency? compile `'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'`

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what is the wrong of your code. Please refer this: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md.